# Example of a nonmeasurable function $X$ equals a measurable function $Y$ on set $A$, with $\mu(A^c)=0$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

> If $X$ (which is not measurable) equals a measurable function $Y$ on a set $A$ having $\mu\left(A^{c}\right)=0,$ then $\int X d \mu \equiv \int Y d \mu .[$ It is trivial that the value $\int X d \mu$ is independent of the choice of $Y$ and $A .]$

I quoted this sentence from the book *Probability for Statisticians* in the chapter of Lebesgue Integral. Our teacher explains that (if I understand correctly) this paragraph simply means if we ignore the null set, which doesn't really matter in the Lebesgue setting, even if we are given a nonmeasurable function, as long as it equals to the measurable function $X$ on $A$, we can still obtain the Lebesgue integral. It is hard for me to picture what is a non-measurable function and how can a non-measurable function equals to a measurable function on a set. Could someone please give me an example?

Comment: what is the sigma algebra of measurable sets you are working with?

Comment: @dessind'enfantterrible from $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)\rightarrow (\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{\overline{B}})$

Comment: if $\mathcal{A}$ is unspecified, you can always take something like $\mathcal{A}= \{\Omega, \emptyset \}$ to easily cook up non-measurable functions.  Then any non constant function is not measurable

Comment: @dessind'enfantterrible Is it possible to give a solid example if you don't mind?

Comment: @dessind'enfantterrible I think I know a non-constant $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is non-measurable with respect to trivial sigma-algebra, but I also need $X=Y$ on $A$ with $\mu(A^c)$... I am very confused with the concept of measurable function. I am hoping if you can provide a solid example, it may help me understand the concept better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the real line $X$ with the sigma algebra of Borel sets and the Lebesgue measure. Let $C$ be the Cantor set. It is known that not every subset of $C$ is  Borel set. [The class of all Borel sets has cardinality $c$ whereas the power set of $C$ has cardinality $2^{c}$]. Now let $X=I_C$ and $Y=I_E$ where $E$ is a subset of $C$ which is not a Borel set. Then $X=Y$ on $C^{c}$ and $\mu (C)=0$.  $X$ is Borel measurable and $Y$ is not. Also, $X$ and $Y$ are both Lebesgue measurable and $\int X d \mu=\int Y d\mu=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much this example helps a lot. I am not sure about the cardinality of the power set but I think I get the idea.